# Lateral acceleration caused by a spinning frame of reference

Tags: experimental-physics, relativity

Here's a thought experiment.

If there's an astronaut infinitely far away from the equator of the Moon and he has a laser pointer pointing perfectly downwards on the surface of the Moon and he throws a feather.

Will the feather collide on the surface of the Moon exactly where the laser spot is or will it be slightly accelerated in the same direction of the rotation of the Moon?

I guess the Sagnac correction will take place.

Comment: By what mechanism would the feather be pulled along in the direction of the Moon's rotation? Is this a purely classical question, or are you wanting to consider the effects a rotating mass has on space-time using GR?

Comment: Gravity. It is both a classical and modern question.

Comment: Sorry I was wondering if this test has been done before. Because I suspect rotating frames of reference (graviton fields) to drag a falling objects in the same rotation as theirs.

Comment: Ok so you do want an answer involving GR? I would add more detail to the question as well as put on more relative tags. And I don't think anyone has been infinitely far away from the moon and pointed a laser at it and then threw a feather at the moon to see what happens.

Comment: Yes please. The classical notions won't bring anything new I think.

Answer (score 1):

The feather will not fall. Instead, it will keep orbiting the moon together with the astronaut.

The radius of the circular trajectory is given by $r = \frac{v^2}{a}$ and, since the inicial velocity of the astronaut is the same of the feather, there's no reason for the distance between then change.

Comment: You're right. I should have specified that the astronaut is infinitely far away and he throws a feather towards the Moon.